# How to split a nested list of ints into a a list

Tags: python

```
lst = [[1, 5],  
       [2, 2]
```

this is my nested list, I need to make a list of the points of this:

```
output = [[1, 5, 2, 2]
```

here is my attempt at this which works for this case but fails if I have an example where the row length is 6 or greater than 4

```
new_lst = []

for x in range(len(lst)):
    for y in range(0, len(lst[x]), 2):
        new_lst.append([lst[x][y],lst[x][y+1]])

counter_a = 0
counter_b = 1
output = []

while counter_b - 4 <= len(lst):
    output.append(new_lst[counter_a] + new_lst[counter_a + 2])
    output.append(new_lst[counter_b] + new_lst[counter_b + 2])
    counter_a += 4
    counter_b += 4

print(output)
```

Comment: From Review: This question lacks any code to show us that you've made any attempt to solve this yourself. If you've tried something, show us what you've tried, example of the expected output and what you're actually getting. If you haven't tried anything, you need to do that before posting. We can help you with your existing code, but we won't write it for you. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: [Formatting posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) ... [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) ... [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? This is general for all lists with size nxm where n and m are even numbers. The logic is to iterate with a step of 2 in both row and column, then take the block of 2x2 elements and append it to the output list.

```
lst = [[1, 6, 5, 6],  
       [2, 5, 6, 8],  
       [7, 2, 8, 1],  
       [4, 4, 7, 3]]
output = []

for j in range(0, len(lst), 2):
     for i in range(0, len(lst[0]), 2):
         output.append([lst[j][i], lst[j][i+1], lst[j+1][i], lst[j+1][i+1]])

output : [[1, 6, 2, 5], [5, 6, 6, 8], [7, 2, 4, 4], [8, 1, 7, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
print([x for i in list(zip(*[[i[:2], i[2:]] for i in lst])) for x in [i[0] + i[1], i[2] + i[3]]])
```

Comment: can you simplify that down into multiple lines?

Comment: @KvnPatel I first splitt every sublist into two, then i transpose it and seperate agin into two then you're done, please up-vote  every answer as well